# Добавление обработчика события в VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Какова аналогичная конструкция для следующего в VB.Net? Как-то через AddHandler нужно будет?

`_model.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName); };`

Comment: [VB lambda-expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) уже читали? Что не получилось?

Comment: Текущее название вопрос совершенно неинформативно. Пожалуйста сделайте нормальное описательное название

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, @rdorn, за данный комментарий. По сути уже сам дошел до верного, но ссылка оказалась в целом полезной. Ранее не натыкался почему-то на нее.

Итог вышел таким:

```
AddHandler _model.PropertyChanged, Sub(s, e)
                                           RaisePropertyChanged(e.PropertyName)
                                       End Sub
```